# JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException when running a Batch-Task in Spring cloud Dataflow

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have a Batch job working as a Task in spring cloud dataflow. When i try to execute the same task Definition a second time i get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:793)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
    at com.tigerbooks.importer.ImportTask.main(ImportTask.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={-spring.cloud.task.executionid=3, -spring.datasource.username=dataflow_stage, -spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.59.254.101:3306/dataflow_staging, -spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver, -import.import-audio-content=false, -spring.datasource.password=bVs64CMlKvcTdkRLWL2zNPANYD3HMB, -import.syncfolder=/import-integrationtest, -spring.cloud.task.name=Integration-Test, -spring.profiles.active=ftp01,dev}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java
```

My Job configuration looks like this:

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Job importJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("Import-Products").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(step1())                
            .next(step2())
            .end()
            .build();
    }
}
```

As far as i found out, a JobParametersIncrementor is supposed to fix this exception by adding a incrementing runId to the parameters. But in my case i can only run the job once on the server, then i have to clear the database (mysql) and the RunId is nowhere in the database.

Comment: The run id isn't getting set.  Are you sure the version of the code you're running is the version you think?  Also, if you're adding the run id incrementer after a failed instance, I think you'll have to clear out the records for that failed instance...

Comment: @MichaelMinella thank you soooo much. i used the wrong docker-image-version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Michael Minela already guessed my jobs where started with the wrong docker image-version. So the RunIdIncrementer was not present and it did not work.

After registering a new app with the correct version everything worked. Thanks.